# What does "crank it" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *F9: The Fast Saga* (2021), Dom and Mia are trying to stop
am armored truck using an electromagnet:

> Dom: **Crank it**. If we can't break through, we stop it.

Then they make surrounding cars attracted to the armored truck.

What does "crank it" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, "crank it" is "crank it [up]", meaning "increase the (volume/power/etc.) of something." Dom is telling Mia to put the electromagnet to maximum power.